# Custom route for edit method without ID in URL

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6

I want to make a settings screen for my users, and I want the URL to be easy an memorable: `domain.com/user/settings`

I want this route to point use the `UserController@edit` method, however, the `edit()` method requires ID parameter.

Is there someway I can use `user/settings` URL without specifying the ID in the URL, but still use the same `edit()` method in the `UserController`?

Answer (score 1):

The edit URL could be use without any parameter. In that case you can mention the user in controller.

**Route**

```
Route::get('user/settings');
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I managed to solve it?

`web.php`:

```
Route::get('user/settings', 'UserController@edit')->name('user.settings');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

`UserController.php`:

```
public function edit(User $user = null)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
}
```